# AttributeError: module 'streamlit_tags' has no attribute 'set_page_config'

Tags: python, streamlit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soQvc.png)

What to do to solve the error?
I am using Python version 3.10.5 and streamlit version 1.10.0.

Comment: Start with posting your code and error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you posted, I'm guessing that your code does something like the following:

```py
import streamlit_tags as st
```

In that case, you are overwriting the convention of Streamlit being referenced as `st`, and you either copied a code example from somewhere that shows `st.set_page_config` or it is a simple mistake.

To resolve this, I would do the following in your code (or similar, doesn't matter what you reference the other library as):

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit_tags as tags
```